# Segmentation fault in singly linked list C program

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, segmentation-fault

In this code below, when I comment out the first and second call to display() function in main, It works fine. But without commenting, after adding 2nd element it says  - **segmentation fault**.

I am new to pointers. Please suggest what might be wrong.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
//-------------------------------------------------
struct node
{
int data;
struct node *next;
}*start=NULL;
//------------------------------------------------------------

void creat()
{

  struct node *new_node,*current;

  new_node=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

  printf("\nEnter the data : ");
  scanf("%d",&new_node->data);
  new_node->next=NULL;

  if(start==NULL)
  {
  start=new_node;
  current=new_node;
  }
  else
  {
  current->next=new_node;
  current=new_node;
  }
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------
void display()
{
struct node *new_node;
 printf("\nThe Linked List : ");
 new_node=start;
 while(new_node!=NULL)
   {
   printf("%d--->",new_node->data);
   new_node=new_node->next;
   }
  printf("NULL\n\n");
}
//----------------------------------------------------
void main()
{
creat();
display();
creat();
display();
creat();
display();
}
```

---

output ->

```
 $./a.out

Enter the data : 4

The Linked List : 4--->NULL


Enter the data : 6
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because of `current->next=new_node;` in else block.
When you enter data second time `start` is declared global so its value persists between function call but as `current` is declared within fuunction it's scope is limited to function only.
So when you enter data second time `current` is null so accessing `current->next` causes segmentation fault.
So declare `current` node after `start` variable.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. Although that solved the problem, my query is if I comment out first two calls to display() and let last call to display() remain as it is then it works fine. If all three calls to display are uncommented then there is this error. Any idea why?

Comment: @User42 you won't like the answer. Its happens because the activation record and local variable memory dissect for successive calls on your platform "assumes" the prior local variables because nothing else has been called that could potentially overwrite them. it is absolutely unreliable, extremely platform-specific, utterly non-standard, and without-question undefined behavior, but I'd bet a dollar that is what you would see if you debugged into successive calls to `creat` with no intermediate calls to *anything else*.

Comment: @User42 the simplest UB-example I can muster that demonstrates what I described above. Note the address of each local variable printed [**in this sample**](http://ideone.com/ElfhsD). Best of luck.

Comment: Though you have not mentioned error I assume error could be that you are not able to print complete linked list.This is happening because `current=new_node` second line in else block.That creates problem.So change you else block as `current->next=new_node;
current=current->next;`.

Comment: @R.S - solution in above comment is not solving the problem.

Comment: @R.S - I just got segmentation fault as given in output section in question above. I think what WhozCraig suggested is the reason for this unwanted,unpredictable behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Second time you call `creat`, you are using an ininitialized `current`.

`current_node` is a local variable with auto storage. When you return from the function, it gets deleted.

Try adding

```
struct node* current = NULL;
```

right after you define `start`. Then, remove it from `creat`.

Answer (score 0):

The offending code is:

```
       current->next=new_node;
```

You are dereferencing a NUll pointer which is illegal. 
What you should have done was to declare current as a global variable as well:

```
struct node
{
int data;
struct node *next;
}*start=NULL,*current=NULL;
```

This will fix your display issue as well.